# How to limit length of properties in logs in WSO2 ESB?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I need to cut body content in logs in WSO2 ESB. For this purpose, I have two parameters in registry: enabled (true or false) and limit (integer, for example: 1024).

For that, I have next expression in a property:

```
<property name="BODY_TO_LOG" expression="fn:substring(get-property('default','BODY'),0,getproperty('default','LIMIT'))" type="STRING" scope="default"/>
```

Note that BODY and LIMIT properties have been set previously.

My problem is it does not limit in logs, although the value of these properties are right.

Is it correct that form of limit the content of property?

Comment: Did you try out this  property with <log level="custom"> or <log level="full">?

Comment: Yes, I did. But I also have to limit the lenght because there is no much free space in disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression should work. I have tested it and came to the nonsensical conclusion that when you declare your LIMIT property with type INTEGER, it doesn't log anything. When you declare your LIMIT property without a type - it works. If you declare your LIMIT property with a type STRING it also works.

So, basically your declaration of the LIMIT property should resemble the following:

```
<property name="LIMIT" type="STRING" value="1024" scope="default"/>
```

or

```
<property name="LIMIT" value="1024" scope="default"/>
```